# Custom tab in Excel Ribbon cannot be activated

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-addins

I am trying this to activate a custom tab:

```
Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon.RibbonUI.ActivateTab("TabAddin")
```

It simply does nothing. No error, no tab activation, nothing.

If I change tab name to a non existing tab, it throws an exception, what it is obvious. That means the ActivateTab method is doing something, but not what it is intended to do.

Any help please? this is VSTO for Excel 2016.

Comment: The [`ActivateTab` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/iribbonui-activatetab-method-office) *method returns S_FALSE if there is no Ribbon or the Ribbon is collapsed*. Have you debugged these conditions?

Comment: @DavidZemens IRibbonUI.ActivateTab returns void

Comment: Did you set your ribbon property 'ControlIdType' to 'custom' ?

Comment: @Malick Yes, I did

Comment: did you check if another tab has already this controlID?  also to be sure: it is not the name but the controlID string that you should provide

Comment: + check there is no special character in tab's name

Comment: @Malick The name is TabLeanAddin. It is the same as the controlID. if i change name, ControlID changes too.

Comment: @jstuardo Sorry it is the same for me, the name changes with the controlID. I have no other ideas..

Comment: @Malick Have you done something similar before? did it work for you? maybe my code is not the problem but a problem in the VSTO library.

Comment: Yes I did it and it works so it's not a VSTO problem.

Comment: I have found where the problem is. I am opening a Book by code, and just after calling Open method, I am tryng to activate the tab. I have realized that this is asynchronous, so when the ActivateTab method is called, the tab is not actually created yet for the opened book. I used excelApp.WorkbookOpen event to try to activate the tab there, but it did not work either. It seems excelApp.WorkbookOpen is called asynchronously also and not after the book was actually opened. Do you know what event can I use? I don't want to use a timer since if the workbook is big, it will take more time to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I was opening the book programmatically and immediately after calling Open method I was trying to activate the custom tab. At that stage, tab isn't created yet (maybe Open method is asychronous), that is why tab was not activated.

Finally I have used this to open the book:

```
var excelApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
excelApp.WorkbookActivate += excelApp_WorkbookActivate;
Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename: fileToOpen);
```

And in other part of the source file, I have:

```
void excelApp_WorkbookActivate(Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Wait(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1));
    this.RibbonUI.ActivateTab("TabLeanAddin");
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WorkbookActivate -= excelApp_WorkbookActivate;
}
```

All the above caused the add-in to work as expected.

Cheers

Jaime